# How to take an exponential of a quantum object in Python's QuTiP

Tags: python, numpy

I want to take all the elements of a quantum object `rho1` (which is basically a matrix/array) and calculate the exponential of the elements to get a matrix/array `rho2`. How do I do this?

Obviously `exp` from `numpy` doesn't work (I get an error `AttributeError: exp`). The `qutip` function doesn't perform my particular calculation and it gives back an array with different dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
import qutip as qt

N = 2
M = 2

# angular momentum
Jp = qt.tensor(qt.qeye(M), qt.jmat(N/2.0, '+'))
Jm = qt.tensor(qt.qeye(M), qt.jmat(N/2.0, '-'))

# make initial state
rho1 = qt.tensor(qt.basis(M,0), qt.basis(N+1,N))
print rho1

# make another state
Jx = (Jp + Jm) / 2.0  # angular momentum
# x = np.exp(1j*np.pi*Jx) * rho1
x = (1j*np.pi*Jx).expm() * rho1
rho2 = qt.tensor(qt.basis(M,0), x)
print rho2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import numpy as np
import qutip as qt

N = 2
M = 2

Jp = qt.tensor(qt.qeye(M), qt.jmat(J, '+'))   # J+
Jm = qt.tensor(qt.qeye(M), qt.jmat(J, '-'))   # J-

# angular momentum
Jx = (Jp + Jm) / 2.0

# initial state
rho0 = qt.tensor(qt.basis(M,0), qt.basis(N+1,N))

R = (1j*0.5*np.pi*Jx).expm()  # rotation transform
rho = R * rho0
```

Answer (score 0):

To do an elementwise exp on a qobj you can operate on the underlying sparse data.

rho2 = rho1
rho2.data.data = np.exp(rho1.data.data)

Comment: OK... could you be a little more specific? If I go `x = np.exp(1j*np.pi*Jx.data.data) * rho1` I get a memory error. Basically my aim is to write `rho2` by having an operator `exp(i pi Jx)` act on the ket `rho1`.